# .each() function jQuery and change event on select

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, each

I've got this

```
var options = new Array("A","B","C");
var selectHtml="";

$.each( options, function( index, value ) {
    var option = value;
    selectHtml += '<select id="p_'+index+'" >';
    selectHtml +='<option  value="p_yes_'+index+'">Yes ' + option + '</option>';
    selectHtml +='<option value="p_no_'+index+'">No ' + option + '</option>';
    selectHtml +='</select>';
});
```

I want to create an alert on each select (p_A, p_B, ...) when the value is changed by the user.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The js you would require would be something like this

```
$(document).on("change","[id^='p_']",function(){
    alert('Alert message goes here');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Append your html to DOM and then use [`.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach events for dynamically generated elements. Use [`attribute starts with selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to attach events to only elements with `id` starts with `p_`. Try this:

```
$(document).on("change","select[id^='p_']",function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/qCqab/1/)**

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have several other select in my document and i want trigger only change of the select p_+index. Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: @user3563571: Updated answer. please check.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in script tag -

```
$("select").change(function(){
    alert("I am clicked");
});
```